# php 7.4, ssh_connect(), "Unable to exchange encryption keys" when connecting to ubuntu 22.04 machines

Tags: ssh, php-7.4, ubuntu-22.04

When using ssh2_connect

```
ssh2_connect($this->host, $this->sshPort)
```

to connect to a server running Ubuntu 22.04
I get the following error on the client

```
PHP Warning:  ssh2_connect(): Error starting up SSH connection(-5): Unable to exchange encryption keys in /root/ssh.php on line 175
PHP Warning:  ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to xxx.xxx.com in /root/ssh.php on line 175
```

I get the following error in the Server auth.log

```
Unable to negotiate with xx.xx.xx.xx port 45574: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
```

I found another thread
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408005/php-7-4-ssh-connect-unable-to-exchange-encryption-keys-only-when-connectin) That asked me to do this, along with other things. No luck at all

```
ssh2_connect($this->host, $this->sshPort , [ 'hostkey' => 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-rsa'])
```

I get same error on the client and the following error on the server

```
Unable to negotiate with xx.xx.xx.xx port 53942: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa [preauth]
```

It looks like ssh2_connect only allows ssh-rsa and ssh-dss.

Has anyone got a solution to allow ssh2_connect to connect to a ubuntu server running 22.04

Cheers